# How to remove a task from a JBPM workflow?

Tags: java, jbpm

Is it possible to remove a task from an existing workflow in JBPM?
I wouldn't like to have a new workflow, only modify the existing one.

I'm using JBPM 3.2.2

Comment: not enough information to help you. Do you mean that you have a flow in use and need to remove one step from it? or you need to skip a task in the flow while execution.

Comment: I have a flow in use and I need to remove a task. I don't know about the possibility of skipping a task, what do you mean?

Comment: Is it possible for you push another version of your flow, in the production.?

Comment: You can't delete, but you can edit the JBPM code to skip the desired task and go automatically to the next node. Check the methods Transition.take , Node.enter and Node.leave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unfortunately ***not*** possible.

The only solution I can think of in this case is the following:

1. introduce an exception in the workflow, so that it stops
2. deploy a new workflow
3. recover the data from the old workflow and start a new workflow up with the old data.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the default H2 database and trying to delete the tasks then,

Go to your username folder, for example, C:\Documents and Settings\  and delete two following H2-related database files,

1. jbpm-db.h2.db
2. jbpm-db.lock.db

Restart the process. It should work fine. Basically, navigate to the folder where your .eclipse or .m2 folder, etc. are created and delete the two files mentioned above.

I hope this helps.